# how can i login VB.NET. hashed password created in PHP

Tags: mysql, vb.net

I'm doing a login form in vb.net, but the registrations is in PHP (it's kind of a must in the project).

```
//register
$password = strip_tags($_POST['password'])
$password = $DBcon->real_escape_string($password);
$hashed_password = password_hash($password, PASSWORD_DEFAULT);

//login 
$query = $DBcon->query("SELECT id, username, password FROM users WHERE username='$username'");
$row=$query->fetch_array();

$count = $query->num_rows;

if (password_verify($password, $row['password']) && $count==1) {
    $_SESSION['session'] = $row['id'];
    header("Location: home.php");
    }
```

How can I login using hashed password in my VB.Net login form?

Comment: yeah, how can you call a password??

Comment: `strip_tags` should not be used here, and you must escape only *after* you hash, and only for the purposes of composing a query. This will mangle passwords. Does VB.Net have a bcrypt implementation that's compatible?

Comment: its working in my login page in php. but dont know how to do it in VB.Net